# Vmware server 2.01 - guest says Cable unplugged

Tags: networking, vmware-server

Host: Win2008 R2 Ent, Guest Win2008. Vmware server 2.01.
Host network works fine - I can browse the Net.
Guest starts up fine, but network is down and says in tray "Cable unplugged". Its in Bridged mode. "Repair" connection gives same result - cable unplugged. I tried moving the VM to a new named folder so it re-assigns MAC since I 'moved' it - still 'unplugged'. IP is set correctly. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at Virtual Network configuration and showed no VM adapters in the Nic list on Host. Reinstalled Vmware server (same version) - did a 'repair' install. Now it works. I have tried this with other Guest OS (Win2k8) which did not work either - so I suspected the Host.

Just to be clear: Host = Win2k8 R2 Ent 64bit, Guest=Win2k8 R2 ENT x64. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the virtual network card to be automatically connected at VM startup?

It's quite easy to misconfigure this (I did more times that I like to acknowledge).

Comment: Its set to Auto connect.

Answer (score 0):

probably article below, can be helpfull

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004883